# SequelizeValidationError "userId cannot be null"

Tags: sql, express, sequelize.js, postman

I am working on a social network project. I am testing my requests on postman but I have a problem with my createPost request when I test it on postman I get an error.

***My postman request :***

```
{
    "title": "Un titre",
    "content": "un contenu",
    "picture": "une image",
    "usersId": 1
}
```

***Error on postman :***

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "SequelizeValidationError",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Post.UserId cannot be null",
                "type": "notNull Violation",
                "path": "UserId",
                "value": null,
                "origin": "CORE",
                "instance": {
                    "id": null,
                    "title": "Un titre",
                    "content": "un contenu",
                    "picture": "une image",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-02-08T14:28:08.444Z",
                    "createdAt": "2022-02-08T14:28:08.444Z"
                },
                "validatorKey": "is_null",
                "validatorName": null,
                "validatorArgs": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

***models:***

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.STRING,
    picture: DataTypes.STRING,
    usersId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    models.Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: { //application clé étrangère posée sur la table
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  };
  return Post;
};
```

***controllers :***

```
const models = require('../models');

exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
    let title = req.body.title;
    let content = req.body.content;
    let picture = req.body.picture;
    let usersId = req.body.usersId;

    models.Post.create({ title: title, content: content, picture: picture, usersId: usersId})
    .then((response) =>{
        res.status(201).json(JSON.stringify(response));
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error })
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json(error))
};
```

thank you very much for your help (I'm still a beginner, there will surely be some mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an explicit foreign key field described in the model then you need to indicate it in the association:

```js
models.Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: { //application clé étrangère posée sur la table
        allowNull: false,
        name: 'usersId'
      }
    })
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I tried to fix it with your advice but I keep getting this error when I make my request.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `Post.belongsTo` elsewhere? Is it the error has the exact same `path` and `message` values?

Comment: Yes i'm sure about that :/

Comment: Do you have `User.hasMany(Post` ?